# Query Restful API Passing Username and Password

Tags: rest, service, restful-architecture, rest-security

I am building a Restful API for my users.

I have these:
1. GET          -> Users/{id}                    This is to get by Id 
2. POST         -> Users/{DTO}                   This is to add 
3. PATCH/PUT    -> Users/{DTO}                   This is for updating the info 
4. DELETE       -> Users/{id}                    Removing 
5. DELETE       -> Users/{username}/reset_pass   Reset Password 
6. POST         -> Users/?username={userName}&password={password}

So I am a little unsure about number 5 and 6 (specially 6).

I would like to know what you think about this ? sending my user's password in a query string in the Body.

I think Uber uses the pattern that I used for resetting password. What do you think about that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
4. DELETE -> Users/{id} Removing 
5. DELETE -> Users/{username}/reset_pass Reset Password
```

- This is not consistent. You either identify by user IDs or user names. If you want both, use different URL naming schemes.
- `reset_pass` is verb like. Consider using `DELETE Users/{id}/password`. Depending on what happens to the password, `DELETE` may or may not suit the use case.

`6. POST -> Users/?username={userName}&password={password}`

Again, this is not consistent with your URL format. If you'd like to create a new password for a user, use `POST Users/{id}/password`.

> I would like to know what you think about this ? sending my user's password in a query string in the Body.

It is neater to model it into a request body, however it makes no difference in terms of security. Unless you use `HTTPS` anyone will be able to sniff a `HTTP POST` regardless of where in the request you decide to pass your data.

Comment: Thanks, Deepak. I like your answers. I am going to change number 6. What if my delete endpoint is not going to delete the user permanently ? We will have to soft delete the user in this case ?

Comment: I am still unclear about number 5. We are going to generate a token and send an email to user with a link to click. So I am not sure if I have to use DELETE for that ? MAy be PATCH is a better alternative ?

Comment: You cannot email links to `DELETE` or `PATCH` directly. Clicking on those results in a `GET` request. Write a simple HTML page that can make ajax requests using the `DELETE` HTTP method and email that link with parameters. You can soft or hard delete behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my opinion, but on #6 maybe putting the password in the JSON body of the `POST` request would be better. That way it isn't directly in the URL (and I think the REST principles say that when you `POST` you should have the body be the object that is being posted).

Of course, these passwords should already be hashed so it's not too big a deal, but it just seems safer/nicer.

Comment: This is an internal API and we are protecting our services using Firewall and other security methods. What are your thoughts about this ? I tried to convince my team to use SSL but the architect didn't want to use it.